# WordPress: Useful plugins for building a user manual?

Tags: php, wordpress, documentation

What are some recommended WordPress plugins that make building an online user manual more effective? I've been browsing the plugin directory, but was wondering if anyone has already been down this path and could make some recommendations.

Edit: Doh! Using a wiki didn't even occur to me until these responses! I started building a site using WordPress and it seems I had a bit of "tunnel vision".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dokuwiki etc.

Answer (score 2):

MediaWiki is extremely easy to use, and I think would make an exceptionally better platform for a user manual over wordpress. Wordpress may excel at being a front end CMS but it doesn't handle an extensive network of pages very well at all.

**EDIT** - I run a couple of different MediaWiki installations, and they are just as easy if not easier to maintain than Wordpress (which I use for my blog)

Answer (score 0):

Using blogging software to make a user manual seems extremely unconventional. Have you considered using wiki software instead? For example, MediaWiki, which is also written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with thaBadDawg. WordPress uses a single dropdown to allow you to select a Parent Page for the current page (hence a hierarchy). That works fine... until a lot of pages start piling up. Wikis are comparatively better suited for handling the type of structure you'd need.